# build a cakephp query with nested ANDs, ORs, and related model conditions

Tags: database, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to retrieve data based on a few nested conditions as well as the values of related models.

So for example the pseudo code below would find rows in the `Models` table where `Models.type` is one of the selected values (`'mk1'`, `'mk2'`, OR `'mk3'`) AND `Models.style` is one of selected values (`'new'`, OR `'old'`), AND the field of the related model `OtherModels`, `OtherModels.status` is either `active` OR `pending`.

```
$query = $this->Models->find()
  ->contain(['OtherModels'])
  ->where(['Models.type' => ['mk1', 'mk2', 'm3'])
  ->andWhere(['Models.style' => ['old', 'new'])
  ->andWhere(['OtherModels.status' => 'active', 'pending'])
  ;
$data = $query->all();
```

This code doesn't actually work, but is here for illustrative purposes. How would I write working code?

Comment: `'Models.type IN' => ['mk1', 'mk2', 'm3']` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't use the `IN` keyword.

```
$query = $this->Models->find()
  ->contain(['OtherModels'])
  ->where(['Models.type IN' => ['mk1', 'mk2', 'm3'])
  ->andWhere(['Models.style' => ['old', 'new'])
  ->andWhere(['OtherModels.status' => 'active', 'pending'])
  ;
$data = $query->all();
```

more details **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses**